# Get formatted SIM card number on BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, sim-card

In my application I need to get the SIM card number.  I am getting that with `SIMCardInfo.getIMSI()`, but in some other format.

My SIM number is 89919400002018929130, but I am getting: 404940.20.189291.3

I used the following code:

```
   try 
    {
       currentSimNo = GPRSInfo.imeiToString(SIMCardInfo.getIMSI());
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The [imeiToString](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/net/rim/device/api/system/GPRSInfo.html) takes a [IMEI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mobile_Equipment_Identity) not a [IMSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mobile_Subscriber_Identity)

Comment: But the important distinction is whether the byte[] -> String function is different for the two values.

Comment: Point taken, however its not best practice to pass IMSI bytes to a method named imeiToString(byte[] ). I am not familiar with the api I just noticed the IMSI bytes being passed in and smelled a rat.

Comment: I noticed a version that removes the periods from the value which if you are using the method for IMSI detail would be more suited imeiToString(byte[] imei,boolean addPeriods)

Comment: You're not familiar with the API but you're willing to talk about best practices for this API?

Comment: I am familiar with programming and a method named imeiToString that is passed in a IMSI is not what I would consider good code. But I am sure you can tell me differently.

Comment: You're welcome to take it up with RIM.  There's a "submit feedback" button on the top left of the page: http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/GPRSInfo.html

Comment: Thanks for the useful link Michael. I think you'll agree its rather unfortunately named. But it seems the method I mentioned in comment 3 is what is required.

Comment: I agree that it is unfortunately named.

Comment: The method you suggest in comment three is going to return the same set of digits as sampath is getting now, just without the separating '.' characters.  I believe he wants to know why he isn't getting 899194 as the first six digits.

Answer (score 1):

sampath says:

> My SIM number is 89919400002018929130, but I am getting: 404940.20.189291.3

If I line up your two numbers and remove separators, it does look like they are roughly the same:

```
89919400002018929130
    404940201892913
```

Where did you get the first one from?

In the [Wikipedia article on IMSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMSI), you can see that the first three digits are the [MCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mobile_country_codes), then the second three are the [MNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_Network_Code).   So it looks like your SIM is from India, though I don't see a MNC that matches 940.

These values are frequently encoded as [binary-coded decimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal), which is why the imeiToString method needs to be used.

**EDIT**

The IMSI wikipedia article also mentions:

> An IMSI is usually presented as a 15 digit long number, but can be shorter.

I think your code is returning the correct value as `404940201892913`.  Whatever number you are trying to compare it to (899194...) must be encoded differently.