# How to dected IMSI number in Blackberry using programming

Tags: api, blackberry, sim-card

I want to detect IMSI number in Blackberry using java programming.
I think Blackberry and Android almost support API to get IMSI number of SIM card but I don't find it.
Please help me if you known that...
thanks you very much !

Comment: try the following code in real devise which have sim card

Comment: Searching for "+blackberry +imsi" turns up this same question, but already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429885/get-formatted-sim-card-number-on-blackberry

Answer (score 2):

Following is the method to get IMSI number
if simcard is not available then it gives SIMCardException

```
GPRSInfo.imeiToString(SIMCardInfo.getIMSI())
```

try this